# Expected number of return for a random walk on a graph

Tags: probability, probability-theory, graph-theory, random-walk

Let $G$ be a simple, connected undirected graph of order $n$ and vertex set $\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$ and let $P = (p_{i,j})$ be a $n \times n$ matrix where $$p_{i,j} = \left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
  \frac{1}{d(v_i)}  & \mbox{if } v_i \sim v_j \\
  0 & \mbox{otherwise } 
 \end{array}
\right.$$

If we let $\pi = \frac{1}{2|E(G)|}(d(v_i), \ldots, d(v_n) )$ then it is not hard to see that $$\pi P = \pi.$$

Let $H_v$ be the expected number of steps for a random walk to reach back $v$ given that it started the random walk in $v.$

Reading through some textbooks it seems like at this point it should easy to infer that $H_v = \frac{2|E(G)}{d(v)}$ yet I do not see why.

As the comments suggest one needs to apply the law of large numbers yet I do not see how to set up the framework for applying the statement of LLN. Hence I am asking

How do we apply the law of large numbers in this context?

Comment: Because pi(nu)=d(nu)/(2E(G)) (explicit computation + normalization) and H(nu)=1/pi(nu) (strong law of large numbers on the successive visits to nu). All this is most probably explained in the textbooks you are perusing.

Comment: It is not in this respective textbook and I was really trying to find a detailed explanation of this fact online. As an example it is stated at the beginning of page 5 here www.cs.elte.hu/~lovasz/erdos.pdf with no explanation and I've found many notes where the same property is stated as obvious.

Comment: This is because the two facts in my first comment are considered to be already known by readers of these texts. Can you prove them, using the hints in the parentheses?

Comment: @Did Yes I can prove the first one, but I don't seem to know how to apply the law of large numbers in this context.

Comment: Then ask *this*.

Comment: @Did I've modified the question accordingly.

Comment: Hint: by the SLLN, the expected number of steps until the nth return to nu is roughly n.H(nu). On the other hand, by the convergence in distribution to pi of the position of the walk, there are N.pi(nu) returns to nu during N steps. Thus, the nth return occurs at time N such that N.pi(nu) is roughly n. Comparing these yields that n.H(nu) and n/pi(nu) are equivalent when n is large, QED.

Answer (score 2):

Your chain is recurrent (since it is a finite state makov chain).

In this context there is a general formula that relates the invariant measure $\nu(\cdot)$ and the expected time of return $\Bbb{E}[\tau_\cdot]$.

Let $X_0 = i$, define $T_1 = \inf\{k>0, X_k = i\}, T_2 = \inf\{k> T_1, X_k = i\}, \ldots$  Those $T_j$ are the times of first return to the site $i$.

Denote $V_n(i)=\#\{\text{visits to the site } i \text{ in $n$ steps of the chain}\}$.

It is a property of the invariant measure that
$$\nu(i) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{V_n(i)}{n} $$

Now note that
\begin{align}\nu(i) &= \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{V_{(T_1 + \ldots + T_n)}(i)}{T_1 + \ldots + T_n} \\
& = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{\frac{T_1 + \ldots + T_n}{V_{(T_1 + \ldots + T_n)}(i)}} \\\end{align}

Note that $V_{(T_1 + \ldots +T_n)}(i) = n$ and since the $T_i$  are independent and identically distributed (use the law of large numbers here)
$$\lim_k \frac{T_1 + \ldots + T_n}{n} \to \Bbb{E}[T_1]$$

Therefore this gives us

$$\nu(i) =  \frac{1}{\Bbb{E}[T_1]} $$